# Replace all lines that don't start and end with a html tag with itself wrapped in a <p> elements in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have some content from a TinyMCE editor which for some reason doesn't have html tags around some of the content.

I am doing an export and import into a new system and am wanting to clean this up by wrapping all lines, which do not start and end with html tags, in a "p" tag.

For example:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>This is the content of my first paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 2</h1>
This is the content of my second paragraph
<h1>Heading 3</h1>
<p>This is the content of my third paragraph</p>
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>This is the content of my first paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 2</h1>
<p>This is the content of my second paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 3</h1>
<p>This is the content of my third paragraph</p>
```

I am looking for a small solution using RegEx if possible and have tried quite a few things.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: And would you be so grateful to share with us what you have tried?

Comment: Well I can't think of what I can select with regex on the lines that don't have any html tags. So I tried selecting all lines which start with "<" and end with ">", with the thought that i will be able to do the inverse but have had no luck. The regex I was using was: `/<.*>/` but I am new to regex and have a feeling this is wrong in the first place as to me there is nothing defining to match only on the beginning and end of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php). Assertions check for the presence (positive) or non-presence (negative) of its condition in the following (look-ahead) or the previous (look-behind) data, but do not consume any characters.

Like in:

```
<?php

$cc = <<<'EOT'
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>This is the content of my first paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 2</h1>
    This is the content of my second paragraph
<h1>Heading 3</h1>
This is the content of my third paragraph
EOT;

$cc = trim($cc);
$dd = preg_replace('/^\s*(?![<])(.*?)(\s*)$/m', '<p>$1</p>$2', $cc);

echo $dd;

?>
```

See [demo](https://eval.in/551031).

The second parenthesis with `\s+` in it has the only sense too keep your `</p>` on the same line. <strike>However, it would fail if the last line of the content is not terminated by a newline.</strike>

EDIT:

- Allowed for possible whitespace at the start of the line
- Modified expression to allow last line having no trailing newline.

The trim() happens to ensure there is not whitespace at the end of the test data. I also modified the test data to reflect testing possibilities for the new requirements.

The regex does the following things:

- `/^` anchor at the beginning of the line
- `\s*` skip any whitespace at the beginning
- `(?![<])` negative look-ahead assertion: if the next character is a "<", fail
- `(.*?)` capture any content of the line, but du not be greedy
- `(\s*)` so that all whitespace in the end (especially newlines) can be captured by this
- `$` anchor at the end of the line
- `/m` process for multiple lines: `^` can be matched after a newline, `$` before

The line then is replaced by the contents of the first and second parenthesis (leave alone those of the assertion, which is always zero-length and is not captured) plus the HTML tags.

Comment: You are using `negative-lookahead` though

Comment: Corrected, sorry for the typo. "positi*ti*ve" would not have been very appropriate in any way. =)

Comment: well you can use `positive-lookahead` as `^(?=[^<])`..It is tedious though

Comment: This works! However I have hit a new problem. If any line of the html is indented it will still wrap it in a "p" tag. I presume because it isn't accounting for white space at the beginning.

Comment: @JoeGrigg yeah..include white space

Comment: @JoeGrigg `^\s*(?![<])(.*)(\s*)$`